# HTML5 Video: Retain aspect ratio when resizing

Tags: css, video, html

I have a video element set to 100% width in a container div. That div has a max-width of 800px and min-width of 400px. When resizing the browser I need the video element to resize while retaining its original aspect ratio. Currently it resizes in width but remains its original height, adding letterbox bars above and below to make up for it.

Is it possible to resize the video element dynamically like this without resorting to Javascript?

Comment: What did you set the height to? is it a static measurement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [the box model, in the section on replaced elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#inline-replaced), this should work as you expect: Since the video has a `height` of `auto` and a set `width`, and it has [an intrinstic ratio](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#concept-video-intrinsic-height) (as videos do), then the used value of height should be computed based on those. Make sure you are not specifying the `height` anywhere — the following CSS worked for me:

```
video {
    width: 100%;
}
div {
    max-width: 800px;
    min-width: 400px;
}
```

Try explicitly adding `height: auto` to the video — maybe with `!important` to see if it’s getting set somewhere else.

Comment: Hmm. Seems to be working, but now the poster image isn't resizing with it.

Comment: Got it. It was an issue with the library I'm using for adding custom controls. Thanks for the help!